# google navigation api for driving directions

Tags: android, navigation

I am building an Android application for showing a route from source to destination.
In the app, I am finding an optimal path compared to Google Maps path.

But for driving directions, I want an API which will shows the directions from source to destination turn by turn as shown in attachment.

Since I am creating my own path, I have a bunch of latitudes and longitudes from source to destination.
Is there any way I can use my own data(i.e latitudes and longitudes) and show it in the figure shown below?

[image]

Comment: Hi Did you implemented this? please help me I have to implement same like this

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a non-google map for displaying the turn-by-turn directions, it's expressly forbidden in their TOS.